# Preventing Squid from resolving hostnames

Tags: squid

i have Squid 2.7-STABLE7 configured as a reverse proxy/accelerator towards our web server(s). At present Squid is trying to resolve hostnames in the requests it receive in order (I think) to find the right web server to contact.

However, I'd rather Squid forwarded ALL requests for those pages it does not have in cache to an Apache server residing on the same node (say, 127.0.0.1:81), without attempting any address resolution. Is that possible?

Please note that I don't want to alter */etc/hosts*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that behaviour can be changed (it would better to recompile squid with `--disable-internal-dns` option to entirely disable this feature and not waste resources.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not that happy at recompiling, I'd rather use standard packages in my distribution if that's possible. Is there any config option that can be used to disable internal DNS resolution as well?